# Emulate texture2D in Javascript

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl

I have written a shader than transforms vertex positions by a heightmap texture. Because the geometry is being transformed on the vertex shader, I can't use traditional picking algorithms in javascript without reverse engineering the shader to get the vertices into their transformed positions. I seem to be having a problem with my understanding of the texture2D function in GLSL. If you ignore the texture wrapping, how would you go about emulating the same function in JS? This is how I currently do it:

```
    /**
    * Gets the normalized value of an image's  pixel from the x and y coordinates. The x and y coordinates expected here must be between 0 and 1
    */
    sample( data, x, y, wrappingS, wrappingT )
    {
        var tempVec = new Vec2();

        // Checks the texture wrapping and modifies the x and y accordingly
        this.clampCoords( x, y, wrappingS, wrappingT, tempVec );

        // Convert the normalized units into pixel coords
        x = Math.floor( tempVec.x * data.width );
        y = Math.floor( tempVec.y * data.height );

        if ( x >= data.width )
            x = data.width - 1;
        if ( y >= data.height )
            y = data.height - 1;

        var val= data.data[ ((data.width * y) + x) * 4 ];

        return val / 255.0;
    }
```

This function seems to produce the right results. I have a texture that is 409 pixels wide by 434 pixels high. I coloured the image black except the very last pixel which I coloured red (408, 434). So when I call my sampler function in JS:

```
this.sample(imgData, 0.9999, 0.9999. wrapS, wrapT)
```

The result is 1. Which to me is correct as its refering to the red pixel.

However this doesn't seem to be what GLSL gives me. In GLSL I use this (as a test):

```
float coarseHeight = texture2D( heightfield, vec2( 0.9999, 0.9999 ) ).r;
```

Which I would expect coarseHeight should be 1 as well - but instead its 0. I don't understand this... Could someone give me some insight into where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may already noticed that any rendered textures are y mirrored.

`OpenGL` and by that `WebGL` texture origin is in the lower-left corner, where as your buffer data when loaded using a canvas 2d method has a upper-left corner origin.

So you either need to rewrite your buffer or invert your `v` coord.